# How to connect remote postgresql database with datagrip by ssh tunnel?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, datagrip

I want to connect to the remote Postgresql production server with datagrip, using ssh tunnel. I had successfully setup the ssh tunnel configuration and the connection works. But when I try to connect to the psql server, I get an issue `[08P01] ERROR: unsupported startup parameter: extra_float_digits.`
[image]

As I saw in related questions, you need to change pgbouncer settings. But I don't have access to the remote pgbouncer config. Maybe I can change local connection settings to avoid this error?

Comment: It's related to server configuration and I am afraid can only be changed by modifying the following config file on the server side. For more details, please see the solution in the comments:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69203#comment=27-712529